# Google Analytics log entries created with gtag never get sent to server

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I'm trying to use GA4 gtag **without** GTM. When I call `gtag()` the entries are queued up in `datalayer` but never get sent to the Google Analytics server.

I have added the code snippet in my page's HEAD, and I can see that it is running. I call `gtag('js', ...)` and `gtag('config', ...)` as instructed and see those entries in `datalayer`. I also see entries for `gtm.dom`, `gtm.load`, and `gtm.scrollDepth` which were automatically added.

Similarly, when I add an event like `gtag('event', 'some event')` it get's pushed onto the datalayer list. But, the problem is that these items in datalayer never get sent to the GA server. I don't see any traffic to the GA server in Chrome's developer network view, and datalayer never get's emptied out.

I don't see any errors in the console.

I know that my GA tag is setup correctly because if I try to log events using the gtag SDK like below, then that works and I can see the events in GA. But, I would like the full gtag functionality working.

```js
fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${GATag}&api_secret=${ApiSecret}`, {
body: JSON.stringify({ client_id: ClientId, events: [gaEvent], user_id: _userId }),
method: 'POST',
});
```

Do I need to do anything to cause gtag to actually send the data added to dataLayer? Or does anyone have any suggestion on how to debug this?